# Value of float changes on assignment in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

When I assign **2.3211232f** as value to a **float** variable in **Java** it is assigned as **2.3211231** to that variable.
Why does this happen ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5221149)

Comment: Any particular reason to use float rather than double?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, floating-point values are denominated in units of powers of two. For numbers between 2 and 4, the unit used for `float` is 2<sup>−22</sup>. This is because `float` has 24-bit significands, so, when the high bit represents 2<sup>1</sup>, as it must for numbers between 2 and 4, the low bit represents 2<sup>1−23</sup> = 2<sup>−22</sup>.

2<sup>−22</sup> is 0.0000002384185791015625, so the representable numbers between 2 and 4 are spaced in steps of that size. The representable numbers near 2.3211232 are:

- 2.3211228847503662109375
- 2.3211231231689453125000
- 2.3211233615875244140625

Of those, 2.3211231231689453125000 is the closest to 2.3211232, so, when the source text `2.3211232f` is converted to `float`, the result is 2.3211231231689453125000.

Java’s default formatting displays this as “2.3211231”, because it uses just enough decimal digits to uniquely identify the value. It does not show all the digits of the exact value, so it misrepresents the value. Never take the result of default formatting as the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

A Java `float` is a 32-bit floating-point value. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) says:

> This gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision.

Your number has 8 digits, and it seems that it exceeding what a `float` can handle.

If you want to see the precision at the value you have, call the [`Math.ulp(float f)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-float-) method.

If you want to see what next value down/up a `float` can handle, use the [`Math.nextDown(float f)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextDown-float-) and [`Math.nextUp(float f)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-float-) methods.

```
float f = 2.3211232f;
System.out.println("f    = " + f);
System.out.println("down = " + Math.nextDown(f));
System.out.println("up   = " + Math.nextUp(f));
System.out.println("ulp  = " + Math.ulp(f));
```

*Output*

```
f    = 2.3211231
down = 2.321123
up   = 2.3211234
ulp  = 2.3841858E-7
```

As you can see, your value `2.3211232` cannot be stored in a `float`, because the next value up from `2.3211231` is `2.3211234`.

As the ULP (Unit in the Last Place) shows, the precision at the last (7th) digit is 2.4, so there is between 2 and 3 steps in the 7th digit between adjacent values.